# How to solve for $x$ in $\frac{1}{1+x}\cdot\frac{1}{1-x}=A$ where A is less than 1?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can we solve for $x$ in the equation:

$$\frac{1}{1+x}\cdot\frac{1}{1-x}=A$$

where 0 < A < 1

Comment: Common denominator?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I forgot to add that 0 < A < 1. I just edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us suppose $A\neq 0$ (otherwise there is no solution), you have
$$ \frac{1}{1+x}\frac{1}{1-x}=A\iff(1+x)(1-x)=\frac{1}{A}\iff 1-x^2=\frac{1}{A}\iff x^2=1-\frac{1}{A}$$
If $A<1$, $1-\frac{1}{A}<0$ and there is no solution in $\mathbb{R}$, if $A>1$ there are two solutions : $x=\pm\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{A}}$ and if $A=1$, the unique solution is $x=0$.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to add that A< 1. I just edited my Question. What is the solution in complex plane? Thanks

Comment: You have to add an $i$ to the solutions : if $A<1$ the solutions are $\pm i\sqrt{\frac{1}{A}-1}$.

Comment: Thank you Tuvasbien.